# Creation menu in Blender 2.8

Tags: edit-mode

Why when I create an object (ex: a UV Sphere or a Cylinder) in a file I am working on, it doesn't show anymore the option of how many vertices/radius/depth etc at the moment I just created it. Previously worked well but I don't know what happened. (if I open a new empty file, it works well again)
I am working in Blender 2.8

Answer (score 0):

I had default window layout chosen and not "Modeling" one.